# FabricJs 2.1 and Angular 5.2

Tags: angular, fabricjs2

I have been using FabricJS 2.0 rc-3 and Angular 5.0.3 and they worked well together, but now I'm starting a new project and used the current latest stable FabricJS 2.1 and Angular 5.2.7 and they do not work.

This is how I imported Fabric and worked with it earlier without any issue:

```
import { fabric } from 'fabric';
this.canvas = new fabric.StaticCanvas('map-canvas', { renderOnAddRemove: false });
```

In the new project with the new versions this does not work. It compiles, but at runtime I get this:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'Canvas' of undefined
```

I also tried the following import, but that doesn't even compile:

```
/* import 'fabric';
// declare const fabric: any; */
```

I searched the web up and down, but haven't found any clue about how to fix this.

Package.json:

```
{
  "name": "atlas-project",
  "version": "0.9.6",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "build-prod": "node ./build.version.js $CI_BUILD_NUMBER && ng build --environment prod --target=production --aot",
    "build-staging": "node ./build.version.js $CI_BUILD_NUMBER && ng build --environment staging --target=production --aot",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^5.2.7",
    "@angular/common": "^5.2.7",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.2.7",
    "@angular/core": "^5.2.7",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.2.7",
    "@angular/http": "^5.2.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.2.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.2.7",
    "@angular/router": "^5.2.7",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^1.0.0",
    "@types/google.analytics": "0.0.36",
    "@types/ramda": "^0.24.18",
    "ajv": "^6.2.1",
    "angularfire2": "^5.0.0-rc.6",
    "bootstrap": "^4.0.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "fabric": "^2.1.0",
    "firebase": "^4.10.1",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "jsoneditor": "^5.11.0",
    "jw-bootstrap-switch-ng2": "^1.0.8",
    "node-sass": "^4.7.2",
    "ramda": "^0.25.0",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.6",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.14"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^1.7.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.2.7",
    "@angular/language-service": "^5.2.7",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.92",
    "codelyzer": "^4.2.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
    "karma": "~1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "replace-in-file": "^3.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~3.2.0",
    "tslint": "~5.7.0",
    "typescript": "^2.4.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your package.json?

Comment: Added it to the description

Comment: Will this work for you? `import * as fabric from 'fabric';`

Comment: Thank you, @yurzui. This did the trick.